# setting up development environmrnt for netty

Tags: java, netbeans, frameworks, netty, nio

I have wrote an application using java NIO but I want implement that using Netty framework because NIO is a low level framework and it's not optimized. I have found a book for learning Netty but my problem is that I don't know how can I setting up development environment for netty and use netty library in my IDE. I downloaded netty jar file and added it to my library but some of classes didn't exist, for example EventLoopGroup. If I could use netty library in netbeans IDE it's better for me. My os is windows 7. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try Gradle and add a compile dependency in your build.gradle such as:

```
compile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final'
```

If you choose not to use Maven or Gradle, ensure you downloaded the netty-all jar, such as netty-all:4.0.23.Final.jar

Comment: I had added incorrect jar file to my library but the correct jar file is netty-all-4.0.23.final.jar. I had added netty-3.6.2.final.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This is from netty's github:

> You require the following to build Netty: Latest stable Apache Maven

Create Maven project and add dependency. Here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty you can choose version and then code of your dependency will be generated. Put this code into your POM file and update project.

If you are not familiar with Maven, go here http://maven.apache.org/